# Show only today in full calendar

Tags: jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I have View where I using fullcalendar plugin.

Here is code of View:

```
 <div  id="calendar"  style="height: 90%; width: 100%; clear: both; display: inline-block;overflow-y:hidden ">

    </div>

<script> //Calendar initialization
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        events:"/Calendar/GetEvents/",
        firstDay: 1,
        editable: true
    });
});
```

But in another View I needs to show only today date. Like here in design

[image]

How I can do this in fullcalendar?

Comment: just create a second calendar object on another div, with all the same settings, except it only allows the agendaDay view, and the default date is today, and there are no buttons to change the day.

Answer (score 0):

You can set calendar settings in a separate object and recreate FC view with function.

```
var $fc = $("#calendar");

var options = { // Create an options object
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  events:"/Calendar/GetEvents/",
  firstDay: 1,
  editable: true
}

$fc.fullCalendar(options);

function recreateFC(/*arguments*/) { // This will destroy and recreate the calendar  

  if (/*your condition here*/) {
    options.defaultView = 'agendaDay';
  } else {
    options.defaultView = 'agendaWeek';
  }
}
```